# Prove tautology without truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This has been asked before, but I have different problems. I’m asking because this was not discussed in class and I’m unsure of the procedure in obtaining the proof. The two in question are the following (simple, I know, but I’m having serious trouble.)

A. $(p  \land q) \to q$

B. $p \to (p \lor q)$

I feel really, really bad about not being able to understand these. According to the book, the answer is that A is a tautology by conjunction and that B is a tautology by disjunction. I understand that. However, I don’t think that my teacher will accept those as part of the proof — we have to use the laws (Idempotence, De Morgan’s, etc.).

Comment: You can use the fact that $p \wedge q $ is a macro for $\sim ( p \Rightarrow \sim q )$ and that $p \vee q $ is a macro for $ \sim p \Rightarrow q $. Then use Hilbert Calculus axioms, you will get there for shure using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $x \to y$ is equivalent to $\neg x \lor y$:

\begin{align*}
(p \land q) \to q
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \neg(p \land q) \lor q &\qquad\text{by definition of }\to \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \neg p \lor \neg q \lor q &\qquad\text{by DeMorgan's Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \neg p \lor \top &\qquad\text{by Inverse Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \top &\qquad\text{by Domination Law} \\
\end{align*}

You might have different names or use different notation here, but the same logic applies. See if you can do something similar for the other problem.

Comment: ... and maybe associativity (used here implicitly by not using parentheses) needs to be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Perhaps:

\begin{align*}
p \to (p \lor q) 
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \neg p \lor (p \land q) &\qquad\text{by definition of}\to \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad (\neg p \lor p) \lor q &\qquad\text{by Associative Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \top \lor q &\qquad\text{by Negation Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \top &\qquad\text{by Domination Law} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: @user3072758 Careful! You should use Distibutivity instead of Associativity, since $\land$ and $\lor$ are different.

Comment: Actually, @Adriano, the OP switched from disjunction to conjunction of $p\land q$ in the first step. Error, typo? Should be $\lnot p\lor(p\lor q)$. So associativity is fine, to follow. user3072758 You can use your proof, but you transcribed incorrectly on the first step.

Comment: Yes @amWhy…typo! :) No wonder I was so confused by @Adriano’s comment.

Comment: Ah I see. Looks good then!

Comment: So @amWhy, it’s this: \begin{align*}
p \to (p \lor q) 
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \neg p \lor (p \lor q) &\qquad\text{by definition of}\to \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad (\neg p \lor p) \lor q &\qquad\text{by Associative Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \top \lor q &\qquad\text{by Negation Law} \\
&\qquad\equiv\qquad \top &\qquad\text{by Domination Law} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, @user3072758, that's just fine.